# confused with div handling

Tags: html, firebug

I have the following HTML code

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"/>
        <div id="main"/>
        <div id="footer" />
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But using tools like firebug I see the is rendered like:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="main">
            <div id="footer" >
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

It's the standard behavior?
How avoid this intentation of Divs?

Comment: Indentation of the div's is just standard formatting as the tabs don't matter (the code is equivalent). Is actually makes the code much more readable. You shouldn't even want to avoid it since there is absolutely no reason for you to do so.

Comment: It's a non-void element and non-void elements can't be self-closed. When in doubt use the validator  http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div>` is an element with content. You cannot use the self-closing tag (`<div />`) unless you are using XHTML.

Write:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also note that just giving an XHTML doctype isn't enough, you have to actually use Content-Type application/xml. With text/html all browsers use normal self-closing rules (e.g. no <script/> and <div/>)  and this is also standardized behavior in HTML5

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="main"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that DIV is necessary a pair tag. Browsers when rendering try to fix the input document structure. Try to see what happens, when you give it completely invalid document. You might also try to validate your documents against W3 validator.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="header">
            content of header
     </div>
     <div id="main">
           main content
     </div>
     <div id="footer">
          content of footer
     </div>
</div>
```